# Change the time of a NSTimer which is in loop

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have this code that opens a particular method always for 4 seconds:

```
float timer = 4.0;

-(void)Start{

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timer
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(go3)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

}

-(void)go3{

NSLog(@"Show now this messange in 1.0 seconds");

timer = 1.0;


}
```

The problem with this code is that I am trying to modify the time loop of 4 seconds to 1 seconds but it seems not to work, what would be the alternative to make the logic of my code work?

Comment: what you exactly want to achieve... right now it will call go3 every 4 seconds...

Comment: do you to call go3 every 1 second but for time after 4 seconds?

Comment: Yes @FahimParkar, that code you post works for me!

Comment: I know that will work but its looping inside loop... that's why i delete answer... if u see number of nslog at one time must be increasing...

Comment: mark it accepted if it works.. i undelete answer...

Answer (score 0):

You will need below.

```
float timer = 4.0;

-(void)Start{

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timer
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(go3)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];

}

-(void)go3{
    NSLog(@"Show now this messange in 1.0 seconds");
    timer = 1.0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timer
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(go3)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 4.0f;

-(void)doSomething
{
    if (something happened) {
        interval = 1.0f; // change time when you need it
    }else if (you want to stop it) {
        return;
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:interval];
}
```